# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion

From the floating header on meta:

> Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes what your site is about. Every word counts!
>
> Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:
>
> the tagline
> the motto
> the blurb under the logo
> a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
> perhaps eventually the domain name in some form

Would the tagline from the Jewish Stack Exchange work but for Christianity?

- Christian Life and Learning

Comment: This question is crucial to this site. It's admittedly very early days, but right now, the questions on main don't inspire me with great confidence for the future of the site. We need to struggle for some kind of identity and unity of purpose. At the moment there seem to be a lot of hair-splitting type 'intellectual' questions.

Comment: Do we get to pick the domain for this site too?

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately they will only give us Christianity.stackexchange.com till we reach serverfault,com levels which I think is bogus.

Answer (score 6):

> We are a site devoted to asking and answering questions related to
>   Christianity. We welcome questions from all traditions and Creeds
>   and do not discriminate. We seek to learn from and educate each other
>   in a way that is non-confrontational and exemplifies the teachings of
>   Christ

-- With all due credit to wax eagle.

Comment: A very good <strike>one</stike> three liner. Based on [this discussion](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/137/denomination-vs-sect-vs-faith-vs-tradition/141#141) about the word denomination and others like it I might update this to "We welcome questions from all traditions without discrimination."

Comment: @Caleb: Good call. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Our Elevator pitch should be:

> We are a site devoted to asking and answering questions related to Christianity. We welcome questions from all denominations and Creeds and do not discriminate. We seek to learn from and educate each other in a way that is non-confrontational and exemplifies our relationship with Christ.

Alternative in response to comments:

> We are a site devoted to asking and answering questions related to Christianity. We welcome questions from all denominations and Creeds and do not discriminate. We seek to learn from and educate each other in a way that is loving, exemplifying the "Golden Rule" - that we treat each other with the respect we believe we deserve.

Comment: This is good - but not everyone who participates here has a "relationship with Christ".

Comment: From the FAQ _Christianity - Stack Exchange is for committed Christians, experts in Christianity and those interested in learning more._  I have to agree with your point, but at some point we need to define a target audience.

Comment: @Kramii - how about an edit that suggest we seek to emulate Christ rather than exemplify our relationship? Is that a bit better?

Comment: @Richard: "Those interested in learning more" explicitly includes those who are not Christians, but have an interest Christianity. You're right about defining our target audience, and I imagine that the majority of participants in this site are likely to be Christians. That said, it would be disrespectful to assume that everyone who posts here is a believer.

Comment: @wax eagle: Personally, I thought the original read better. How about, "We are a site devoted to asking and answering questions related to Christianity. We welcome questions from all denominations and Creeds and do not discriminate. We seek to learn from and educate each other in a way that is non-confrontational and exemplifies the teachings of Christ"?

Comment: @Kramii - you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Scratch that. Our tag line but not our domain should be:

- "Ask and you shall receive"

Comment: Funny, but doesn't explain what the site is about.

Comment: Good tagline, bad elevator pitch

Answer (score -1):

I like `Christian Life and Learning`.

It seems well suited.  It conveys that there can be intellectual discussions at hand, but that it's also a place for more practical questions.

Comment: Would this imply that Christian theology / history is off topic?

Comment: Good tagline bad elevator pitch

Answer (score -1):

From [Advancing in Christian Living and our walk with Jesus](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165/advancing-in-christian-living-and-our-walk-with-jesus/180#180):

> This is a Q&A site not a Church.

This quote in itself probably wouldn't be a great tagline but perhaps a derivation of it would be.

Comment: No. But this would be an awesome comment on two different meta posts. Hedgemage's survivor and Caleb's we are not Christians.

Answer (score -3):

"Christianity.SE is place to search for the Truth about God. Ask Questions and get answers from every point of view.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: its meta. Downvotes signify disagreement here.

Comment: [faq#vote-differences]

Comment: I was curious about the input so that I could revise based on suggestion.

Comment: The truth about which God?