# Advancing in Christian Living and our walk with Jesus

Tags: discussion

Are the questions posted to this website ONLY to be about Biblical study or may they also be related to Christian Living?

Such as 
[How can one overcome lustful desires?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/720/christian-living-how-can-one-escape-the-desires-of-the-flesh-lust)

Can't we also learn how to be better christians by asking christian lifestyle questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As to your question here, **yes, questions about Christian Living** should absolutely be on topic. I think that when asking such questions it would be particularly important to [identify your point of view](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-do-we-avoid-a-vote-contest/122#122) and the point(s) of view you are interested in hearing answers from to avoid threads becoming contentious, but that it is squarely on topic.

As to the specific question you linked, I think it suffers from being too broad a question. There are several directions that you could focus in on that I think would survive much better in this QnA format.

Comment: Yes, on topic provided the specific question falls within the [Guidelines for Good Subjective Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and doesn't become "not constructive" -- *"This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."*

Comment: Yeah, be reasonable - if you're gonna ask how to stay in shape *as a Christian*, make it clear where you're having trouble fitting fitness into faith. Modesty or something. If you're gonna ask how to eat toast *as a Christian*... don't.

Answer (score 7):

I agree [with Caleb](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165/advancing-in-christian-living-and-our-walk-with-jesus/166#166): that **questions about Christian living are on topic**.

> How does a Christian deal with lust?

...is a good question.

> I've got a problem with lust: what should I do about it?

...wouldn't be good.

Why? It is just too personal. As such, we couldn't possibly do the questioner justice. We don't know each other well enough, nor glean sufficient understand each other's personal circumstances from a site like this.

We must, therefore, be clear that the site isn't intended to be a substitute for people within our own churches who know us and care for us. Neither is it a substitute for our prayers and personal Bible study, our own relationship with God etc. Christianity.SE can inform and explain, but it can't can't give personal advice. It shouldn't tell us what to believe, nor tell us how to live your lives. That's our own responsibility.

**This is a Q&A site not a Church**.

Comment: +1, I might make **This is a Q&A site not a Church.** into a meta post at some point. It needs to be part of the definition of the site.